# Comparing excel value with console output using selenium web driver

Tags: excel, selenium-webdriver, conditional-statements

I am storing excel values in 1st array and console output values in 2nd array. Then I am comparing excel value with console output one by one .I have debug code and it stores value proper in arrays. **But it always print "FALSE" even if value matches true.**

My latest code is given below :

```
    WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();


    driver.get("https://www.google.co.in/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=1YaGVMutHcXN8gf39ID4Aw&gws_rd=ssl#q=what+is+software+testing");
    java.util.List<WebElement> links = driver.findElements(By.tagName("h3"));
    int sizecount = links.size(); 
    System.out.println(sizecount);


       //READING DATA FROM EXCEL FROM 1ST COLUMN
        FileInputStream input = new FileInputStream("D:\\sel.xls");
        int count=0;


        HSSFWorkbook wb = new HSSFWorkbook(input);
        HSSFSheet sh = wb.getSheet("sheet1");

        String exceldata[] = new String[20];
        for (int i=0;i<=sh.getLastRowNum();i++)

          {
            HSSFRow row = sh.getRow(i);
            exceldata[i]= row.getCell(count).toString();
            System.out.println(exceldata[i]);
          } 




            String linkdata[] = new String[20];
            for(int j=1;j<=links.size()-1;j++)

            {



                linkdata[j] =  links.get(j).getText();
                System.out.println(linkdata[j]);
            }


            for(int k=0;k<links.size()-1;k++)

            {

            if(exceldata==linkdata)

               {
                   System.out.println("TRUE");


               }
               else
               {

                  System.out.println("FALSE");

               }
            }
              driver.close();

            }


}
```

**Note : I have tried with operator == and .equals both.**

Comment: are you getting correct values from excel.. did you check for excel values?

Comment: @pArAs - Yes I have checked both array by debug and getting all values correct.

Comment: please check the values that you are getting from front end, sometime it happens that the value you get from front end may contain some trailing spaces.. try trimming the values.. it could be the reason.

Comment: @pArAs - sure , can you tell me how can I trim all spaces from value?

Comment: you can directly use trim() method with any of the string, it will remove all the leading, trailing white spaces.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66441/discussion-between-paras-and-helping-hands).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've told you few issues in your program, you can modify your program according to that.

`Issue 1`
When you are storing the value in exceldata and linkdata array, you are taking different index, exceldata array is storing value from index 0 and linkdata is storing value from index 1, so you need to modify your program something like below:

```
for(int k=0;k<links.size()-1;k++){
        if(exceldata[k].trim().equals(linkdata[k+1].trim())){
            System.out.println("TRUE");
        }else{
            System.out.println("FALSE");
        }
    }
```

There was one more issue, I've already told you.

You are good to go now.